# Forward declarations in CapnProto

Tags: capnproto

In a CapnProto schema is there any way to forward-declare structs so you can make a tree structure like this:

```
struct ExecuteProgram {
  code @0 :Text;
}

struct SequenceProgram {
  programs @0 :List(Program)
}

struct IfProgram {
  condition @1 :Program;
  trueBody @2 :Program;
  falseBody @3 :Program;
}

struct Program {
  union {
    execute @0 :ExecuteProgram;
    sequence @1 :SequenceProgram;
    if @2 :IfProgram;
  }
}
```

If I try to compile this the compiler gives the very helpful error message `Parse error`. I assume it is complaining because I use `Program` before it is declared.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you don't need forward declarations, I was just missing a semicolon. What was I saying about `Parse error` being a terrible error message?